# Is it adhering to REST principles if we insert into two tables?

Tags: database, postgresql, https, rest

I am building an application for sports' leagues. At this point I want to create a new season by making use of this endpoint:  
`POST /api/leagues/[leagueName]/seasons`  
This will create a single record in my `seasons` table for that league. In the same request however, I also need to insert the teams within that league into my `season_teams` table in order to keep track of what teams are in any given season.
Since this request now needs to handle a transaction, I was thinking of making use of this endpoint instead (or something similar which has a noun as a resource name):  
`POST /api/leagues/[leagueName]/new-season`  
Is this transaction adhering to REST standards? I cant find a clear answer on whether transactions (multiple inserts in two tables in this case) are allowed.

Comment: REST has nothing to do with database tables. How you store your data is up to you

Answer (score 3):

> I cant find a clear answer on whether transactions (multiple inserts in two tables in this case) are allowed.

They are allowed.

A REST API is a facade; it makes your host look like a web site.  The details of how you implement support for your API are entirely up to you.

It's absolutely normal that a resource be implemented using multiple tables, and that edits to those resources might also span multiple tables.

(Key idea: your "resource model" and your "domain model" are not the same thing, and there is no particular reason to expect them to have a one to one correspondence.)

Comment: Question, wouldn't that become a "service" rather than a REST endpoint? I understand that REST is really more of guidelines than hard set rules (some are harder than others), but wouldn't it become a service if an endpoint is editing more than one table, especially since REST URLs are adding to a URL that usually represent one source of data. 
Like GET "store/products/" is pulling from the products tables alone?

Comment: There is no rule that says a web page must be built from exactly one table.  Resources are generalizations of web pages; therefore there is no rule that says that resources must be built from exactly one table.